# $("html").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow"); if it's at the bottom don't scroll it

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have three buttons which have hidden divs, when i click on one i want the content to scroll to the bottom, then when i click another I want the page to stay where it is but load the new content.

I've tried variables and if statements

```
var i=0;
$('#link-slide13').click(function(){
        if (i==0){//nothing's been scrolled
            $("html").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
            i=1;

        }else{
            //don't do anything
        }
});
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks for the answers!

Edit: Sorry i don't really think i've explained myself, 
http://ephemurl.com/4w/5ws here, is what I have at the minute, the last 6 sections bounce to scroll to the bottom of the document, but i want this to only happen once and then for the next 5 clicks don't animate because you're already there...

Comment: Can you code what you have so far in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use $(body) instead of $(html)

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/APebY/

```
$(function(){
var i=0;
$('#link-slide13').click(function(){
        if (i==0){//nothing's been scrolled
            $("body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
            i=1;

        }else{
            //don't do anything
        }
});
});
```

You can also use unbind within the event trigger to make it run only once

```
$('#link-slide13').click(function(){

            $("body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");

            $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

Comment: Hi there, it's working in chrome but scrolling much further than it needs to.. http://uwptestsite.uwpistol.net/work.html I put the code on image 13

Answer (score 1):

Don't Know what exactly you're trying to do, I guess this should help you,

```
$('#link-slide13').toggle(function(){
    $("html").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
},function(){
    //don't do anything
})
```

Good Luck

Comment: I'm going to try this right now, I really think your onto something, Thanks so much for the help, I was beginning to think it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

We can't watch your html, but I think that you only have applied the function to one button witch id="link-slide13". If it must works in the three buttons change your JQuery selector. (adding a class to all buttons you can select all easy whith $(".className")).

Then, what is a button? a link an input? If the button is a link

```
<a href="#">
```

you can add a "return false" sentence at the end of the function. This prevent that the link works as default and the navegator go to the top of the document.

But, really...what's the problem?

Comment: That prevent default seems to solve one of the issues I have, thanks very much! ... I have an issue with the bottom row of divs, if you click on say the 15 th image, slide15 (the nested div) slides down but the user has to scroll down to see it, I want a code (workable in Chrome) that scrolls the document automatically when the div is revealed.. Does this make sense?