# How can Slow down scroll to top event by jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can Slow down scroll to top event by jQuery animate?

```
$('#go-to-top').click(function() {
   $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 80);
});
```

Comment: @FritsvanCampen it's true that scrollTop isn't a CSS property, but jQuery is nice enough to take care of that for you, so OPs code does work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417080/html-animate-scrolltop-document-height-slow-if-its-at-the-b and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123690/slow-down-scroll-to-top-event-by-jquery-animate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation for the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

You can use "duration" argument to change animation speed and you can provide some custom easing function with the "easing" argument to change animation behavior.

In your case you can do the following to specify animation "speed".

```
$('#go-to-top').click(function() {
   $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
   }, 1500); // 1500 here is the duration of animation in the milliseconds (seconds * 1000)
});
```

I would also recommend to replace window.opera with the jQuery's $.browser.webkit for a better compatibility. [See the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Answer (score 1):

To slow down the scroll you can increase the time it takes to complete the animation. Currently, it's taking 80ms. If you change that number to 1 second, you can see the difference:

```
$('#go-to-top').click(function () {
    $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000); // scroll takes 1 second
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pn5ku/)

You can also add easing effects if you have included the jQueryUI easing library in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
$('#go-to-top').click(function() {
    $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    },2000);// for 2 seconds
});
```

Comment: FYI duration comes after the settings object.