# Using jQuery confirm and scrollTop causing page to scroll up then back down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery-confirm library on a project and when used in conjunction with a jQuery animate the page scrolls to the top and then right back down to the bottom. Here's the code:

```
$.alert({
    boxWidth: '50%',
    useBootstrap: false,
    title: '<p>Questionnaire Errors Found</p>',
    titleClass: 'alert_title',
    content: "<p class='alert_body'>Errors were found in the submitted questionaire and are highlighted in red\n\nPlease review and correct the missing information</p>",
    buttons:    {
        okay:   {
            text: 'Okay',
            btnClass: 'alert_button',
            action: function()  {

                $('html').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#voters_guide_form').offset().top
                        }, 500);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

If I don't use the confirm library the behavior works as expected. Also not using the animate doesn't case the page to scroll at all. I have tried using html,body in the animate with no change and I have moved the animate code in and outside of the alert code but it still does the same thing.

Been through their docs and the internet and I can't seem to find anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$('body')` instead of `$('html')`

[Answer source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417080/html-animate-scrolltop-document-height-slow-if-its-at-the-b)

So you need to change your code to:

```
$.alert({
    boxWidth: '50%',
    useBootstrap: false,
    title: '<p>Questionnaire Errors Found</p>',
    titleClass: 'alert_title',
    content: "<p class='alert_body'>Errors were found in the submitted questionaire and are highlighted in red\n\nPlease review and correct the missing information</p>",
    buttons:    {
        okay:   {
            text: 'Okay',
            btnClass: 'alert_button',
            action: function()  {
                 //Changed to body and added stop
                $('body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#voters_guide_form').offset().top
                        }, 500);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Also, its a good practice to stop the animations running in `body` before you run a new animation. That's why I added the `stop()` method.

**Do note:** If you import this code through an `iframe` it won't work, because with an iframe, you page will now have 2 (or more) bodies and `$('body')` should return an array instead of an object.

Comment: Nope, when I change it to body (with and without the stop call it doesn't scroll up to the top of the page, just 'sits there'

Comment: Hum.. Strange... And are you not loading the script from elsewhere?  Like a jQuery.load() or something like that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about loading. The whole thing is inside a function that validates a form which, of course, is inside document.ready()

Comment: And is your document.ready() (btw its $(document).ready()) inside a <script></script> or loaded from a js file, or even loaded from a HTML file? That's what I'm asking

Comment: Also, have you tried adding a callback function to animate? Does it get triggered? The constructor for animate (complete is the callback)  - animate(properties, duration, easing, complete)

Comment: Have to run for the day, will try the callback in the am ... thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190073/discussion-between-h-figueiredo-and-dc-dalton).